# Convert variable from javascript to php?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

javascript variable **chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "" or enc3=enc4=64** ;
as a above, i look some algorithm in javascript and i wanna to convert that to the php
and i stuck in this, can any body to explaint and write the example about that?
thank for read and answer.

Comment: It works the same way in php `$enc3=$enc3=64;`. After that $enc3 is equal to 64 and $enc4 =64 too. What is your REAL problem?

Comment: Can you explain a little more. Your question gives us no idea what you want. Posting some more code might help.

Comment: Do you want to transfer a javascript variable to php?

Comment: @banzai: See my answer for an explanation of using variables in JavaScript vs. PHP. Please clarify your question (and add in the code you are trying to convert) if you require more information.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are declared like this in JavaScript:

```
var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc3, enc4;
```

After you declare them, you can assign values to them:

```
chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
enc3 = enc4 = 64;
```

The above assignment assigns the value of `""` to `chr3`, and then assigns the value of `chr3` (now `""`) to `chr2`, and then the value of `chr2` is assigned to `chr1`. Now `chr1`, `chr2`, and `chr3` are all empty string variables, equal to `""`. Likewise, `enc4` and `enc3` become variables equal to `64`.

Alternatively, you can declare and assign values to the variables at the same time in JavaScript (this code will do the same thing as both of the code blocks shown above:

```
var chr1 = ""; // Assigns value of "" (empty string) to chr1
var chr2 = "";
var chr3 = "";
var enc3 = 64; // Assigns value of 64 to enc3
var enc4 = 64;
```

In PHP you do not declare variables until you use--or assign values to--them. It works just like the last JavaScript example, except PHP variables are preceded by the dollar `$` sign and do not have the "var" keyword before them:

```
$chr1 = ''; // Assigns value of "" (empty string) to chr1
$chr2 = '';
$chr3 = '';
$enc3 = 64; // Assigns value of 64 to enc3
$enc4 = 64;
```

In both JavaScript & PHP, the equals sign `=` is used to assign values to variables, while a double equals sign `==` is used to check if two things are equal. Example in JavaScript:

```
var testString = "JavaScript Example"; // assign value to testString
if(testString == "JavaScript Example") {
 alert("testString = " + testString);
}
```

The above code will trigger an alert with text `testString = JavaScript Example`. While PHP can't directly create alert boxes, here's a similar example in PHP that echos the value `testString = PHP Example` back to the browser, instead of popping up an alert directly:

```
$testString = 'PHP Example'; // assign value to testString
if($testString == 'PHP Example') {
 echo 'testString = '.$testString;
}
```

As you can see in the above examples, variables, assigning values to variables, and checking if the value of a variable is equal to something else, all work very similarly in JavaScript and PHP. The differences you'll note are:

1. A "var" keyword is normally used to declare a variable before or at its first use in JavaScript, while you just start using the variable in PHP.
2. In JavaScript, a variable is not preceded by anything; it is just a name. In PHP, variables must always be preceded by the dollar `$` sign.
3. Single quotes `'` are preferable to enclose strings in PHP, while double quotes `"` are commonly used in JavaScript.
4. Strings are concatenated, or joined with a plus sing `+` in JavaScript (example: `"StringPart1"+"StringPart2"` outputs `StringPart1StringPart2`), while strings are joined with a period `.` in PHP (example: `'StringPart1'.'StringPart2'` outputs `StringPart1StringPart2`).

There are many more differences between PHP and JavaScript, but hopefully this gives you an idea how to convert a bit of JavaScript code into PHP.

**UPDATE:**

OP (Original Poster) wrote:

> chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "" or enc3=enc4=64 ;

If this is the JavaScript you are trying to convert, it is not valid JavaScript; you cannot have an `or` between value assignments (single `=`). Based on the `or`, the intent would appear to be to check values (double `==`), rather than assign them (single `=`):

```
chr1 == chr2 == chr3 == '' or enc3 == enc4 == 64;
```

This syntax checks that either:

- `chr1`, `chr2`, & `chr3` all are empty strings `""`

or:

- `enc3` and `enc4` both equal `64`

The equivalent PHP would be:

```
((($chr1 === $chr2) and ($chr2 === $chr3) and  ($chr3 === ''))
 or (($enc3 == $enc4) and ($enc4 == 64)))
```